# Get Node.js oracledb result as JSON

Tags: node.js, json, oracle, node-oracledb

I am using the oracledb package to retrieve some data and output the data as json and I have successfully done that but I want the values to be in quotes for example this is the output i get.

```
{
   "postage_charge":0,
   "shipping_charge":52.28,
   "order_processing":9.82,
   "receiving_charge":0,
   "storage_charge":21.36,
   "product_charge":2.65,
   "sup_charge":0,
   "hold_charge":0
}
```

I want it too look like

```
{
   "postage_charge":"0",
   "shipping_charge":"52.28",
   "order_processing":"9.82",
   "receiving_charge":"0",
   "storage_charge":"21.36",
   "product_charge":"2.65",
   "sup_charge":"0",
   "hold_charge":"0"
}
```

here is my code

```
async function selectInvoiceDetail(req, res, invoice) {

    try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "",
        password: "",
        connectString: "192.168.1.5:1521/test"
      });
      
      postageCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as postal_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and charge_type='SHIPPING' and charge_subtype='POSTAGE'`);
      shippingCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as shipping_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and (charge_type='SHIPPING' and charge_subtype='SHIPPING' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='DUTAX' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='SHIPPING' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='VASSHIP')`);
      orderProcessing = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as order_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and (charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='BASE' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='INTNAT' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='LTLCP' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='PACKAGING' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='PIECE' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='PIECEC' or  charge_type='ORDERS' and charge_subtype='SERIAL' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='ORDERS')`);
      receivingCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as receiving_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and (charge_type='RECEIPT' and charge_subtype='PIECE' or  charge_type='RECEIPT' and charge_subtype='ITEM' or  charge_type='RECEIPT' and charge_subtype='PIECEC' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='RECEIVE' or  charge_type='RECEIPT' and charge_subtype='LEVEL')`);
      storageCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as storage_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and (charge_type='STORAGE' and charge_subtype='FLAT' or  charge_type='STORAGE' and charge_subtype='LOCATION' or  charge_type='STORAGE' and charge_subtype='VOLUME')`);
      productCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as product_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and charge_type='PRODUCT' and charge_subtype='SETUP'`);
      supCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as sup_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and (charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='RECEIPT' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='CRETURN' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='LABEL' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='RETURN' or  charge_type='SUP' and charge_subtype='VAS')`);
      holdCharge = await connection.execute(`select sum(item_total) as hold_charge from INVOICE_ITEMS where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' and charge_type='OHOLD' and charge_subtype='PERCENT'`);
      
    } catch (err) {
      return res.send(err.message);
    } finally {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          await connection.close();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
      }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        var result = {
        "postage_charge": postageCharge.rows[0].POSTAL_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "shipping_charge": shippingCharge.rows[0].SHIPPING_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "order_processing": orderProcessing.rows[0].ORDER_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "receiving_charge": receivingCharge.rows[0].RECEIVING_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "storage_charge": storageCharge.rows[0].STORAGE_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "product_charge": productCharge.rows[0].PRODUCT_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "sup_charge": supCharge.rows[0].SUP_CHARGE ?? 0,
        "hold_charge": holdCharge.rows[0].HOLD_CHARGE ?? 0
        };
        
        return res.send(result);
    }
  }
```

any help is appreciated

thank you.

Comment: First comment: do NOT do this `... INVOICE_ID='${invoice}' ...`.  You must use bind variables for performance and security.  `... INVOICE_ID=:i ... ', [${invoice}]`See node-oracledb doc and examples like https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v5.5.0/examples/select1.js#L65-L72

Comment: Second comment: look at wrapping your SELECT statements in a single PL/SQL block and returning the values as OUT binds  (if you use an 'anonymous' PL/SQL block) or via binds as OUT parameters (if you use a PL/SQL procedure).  This would reduce the 'round-trips' to the DB since you would just have one `execute()`, and would make the system more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert number (coming from DB) to string  `.toString()`.
In you results :`(postageCharge.rows[0].POSTAL_CHARGE ?? 0).toString()` and the rest of them which type is number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>convert numbers coming from server to string to get quotes in JSON - toString() Method</h2>
<p>toString() returns the content of a string:</p>
<p> your example woudl be : (postageCharge.rows[0].POSTAL_CHARGE ?? 0).toString(),</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
//your example woudl be 
// (postageCharge.rows[0].POSTAL_CHARGE ?? 0).toString(),
let fromServer  = 123;
let result = fromServer.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[number toString Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Answer (score 0):

Read the node-oracledb manual on [Fetching Numbers and Dates as String](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#fetching-numbers-and-dates-as-string).

Try something like:

```
sql = `SELECT 12.23 AS D FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = :i`;
binds = [1];
options = { fetchInfo: { 'D': { type:oracledb.STRING }} };

result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
console.dir(result, { depth: null });
```

The advantage of this method over converting with `toString()` is that it circumvents Oracle's internal decimal format being converted to Node.js floating point type and removes any subsequent user confusion about the numbers not matching.

I included a bind variable in the WHERE clause as an example since you must change your usage of `... where INVOICE_ID='${invoice}'  ...` to use binding.  This is important for scalability and security.

An alternative to `fetchInfo` is to do the conversion in the SQL statement e.g. like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12.23) AS D FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = :i
```

Since you have a fixed number of SELECT statements and they return simple types, you should consider wrapping them all in a single PL/SQL block.  This will reduce [Database Round-trips](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#database-round-trips) because you only need one `execute()` and it will make the overall system more efficient.  You can do something like:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = { user: 'cj', password: process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD, connectString: 'localhost/orclpdb1' };

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
}

const plsql = `begin
                 select sum(sal) into :salsum from emp where empno > :en;
                 select sum(comm) into :comsum from emp where empno > :en;
               end;`;

const binds = {
  en: 7600,
  salsum: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING},
  comsum: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING}
};

const options = { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT };

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    const result = await connection.execute(plsql, binds, options);
    console.dir(result.outBinds, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```